# Why can't I drag and drop in Firefox or Thunderbird?

Tags: windows-10, firefox, thunderbird, drag-and-drop, windows-10-v1809

I recently upgrade to a new laptop (Win10, Dell XPS13) and copied over my Firefox and Thunderbird profiles from an older laptop.  The latest version of both programs (currently Firefox 96.0, Thunderbird 91.5).

Everything is working great, but I can't do drag-n-drop in either program.  For example, dragging tabs to re-order, dragging a tab outside the window to create a new window, dragging emails into folders, etc. When I click to drag it just does nothing. But I can click and drag to highlight a row of text just fine.  Weird.

Drag-n-drop is working fine in Windows and other programs I've tested.

I've restarted the laptop and run in safe/troubleshooting mode for both programs multiple times.

I've also searched the about:config advanced settings for anything called 'drag' and there is nothing obvious.

I suspect something related to copying over an old profile from the other machine, but I'm not sure what sqlite or json file might need to be deleted. I'd rather not do a 'refresh' and lose everything in my profile.

Any ideas on what I can troubleshoot next???

Thank you.

Update 3/15: 2 months later, still on latest Firefox (v98.0.1) and the problem persists.  One coworker also mentioned having the same problem.  We are both running Windows 10 Enterprise 2019 LTSC (version 1809) so that may be related??

Comment: Did you see https://www.askvg.com/firefox-tip-disable-tabs-drag-n-drop-feature-to-move-to-new-window/ . Sometimes, i t may be necessary to refresh (https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/refresh-firefox-reset-add-ons-and-settings) or to create new profiles.

Comment: Thank you, yes, I did already try toggling the browser.tabs.allowTabDetach setting, no change.

Comment: Works for me. Try to create a new profile and check. If it works, you might consider transferring bookmarks to the new profile and using it instead.

Comment: https://techdows.com/2019/07/fix-firefox-68s-file-drag-and-drop-issues-on-windows.html
https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/windows-administrator-launcher-process-error-fix

Comment: @Gantendo, I a able to drag a text file INTO firefox just fine, so that article is about a different issue.

Comment: @harrymc - I will try making a new profile and adding my bookmarks, etc back into it. thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Does the new profile work better for drag and drop?

Comment: Try to disable all extensions (in Thunderbird) and all plugins & extensions (in firefox). If that solves the issue, find the culprit.

Comment: Does the new profile work better for drag and drop?

Comment: Sorry that I was never able to get around to creating a new profile, however, wanted to report that my Firefox has magically started working again.  I'm guessing it was a recent Firefox update. I'm now on v110.0.1. I am now able to drag to rearrange tabs, including pinned tabs. I can drag a tab outside the window to open in a new window, drag that 2nd window back to the tab bar to consolidate windows, as well as drag a file into the Firefox window and have it open there.  All very handy but alas I have now idea what if anything I did to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Try making a new user by:
Inside Firefox, type or paste `about:profiles` in the address bar and press Enter/Return to load it.

*New Profile*

Click the "Create a New Profile" button, then click Next. Assign a name, ignore the option to relocate the profile folder, and click the Finish button.
Then go to settings then import data from previous user.

Comment: This was previously asked already in the comments below the post. For the moment, we are waiting for word from the OP of whether this helps (before posting an answer).

Answer (score 0):

This is appears to be a thing with Firefox, and I can's find any setting that would fix it. It works flawlessly with Chrome, but I prefer our employees to use Safari as for all other purposes, Firefox works better with our online company management system. The work-around I use is to drag the item onto the desktop, and then drag it into Firefox, then delete the file on your desktop. It's annoying and I wish I could find a fix for it.

Comment: Craig, see my recent comment on the question above. Not sure exactly why, but mine is working again. Try updating and see if any improvement.